# Не работает редирект с передачей данный в сессию

Tags: php, laravel

Сам редирект работает и пересылает куда надо только вот данные в сессии не сохраняет. Ну то есть не работает `with()`.

Мой код:

```
public function section_main(BaseConnection $connection)
{
    // здесь мой код который никак не влияет на редирект и сессии


    // Так работает
    \Session::put('message', '123');
    return redirect()
        ->route('bridge');

    // А так нет
    return redirect()
        ->route('bridge')
        ->with('message', '123');
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Прочёл про with... Как вы используете это в шаблоне?

Comment: Проблема вероятно в том, что `with` добавляет flash-данные. Попробуйте в рабочем коде использовать `flash`. Работает? Редирект обрабатывает браузер (или js на странице или ещё какой-нибудь клиент)?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин нет flash не работает

Comment: @Arendach наводит на мысль, что обработчик запроса, в котором вы ожидаете flash-данные вызывается не сразу после редиректа. flash-данные живут только в течение одного запроса.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин ну тоесть может происходить несколько редиректов?

Comment: @Arendach HTTP-ответ с кодом 302 вы в вашем коде отправляете один раз. Если он действительно отправляется, то дальше его обработкой займётся клиент. Если клиент это браузер, то он перейдёт по урлу из заголовка Location. В обработчике этого запроса flash-данные будут доступны. За пределами кода который вы привели может происходить что угодно и знать об этом должны вы, а не я :-)

Comment: @ЕгорБанин да, клиент браузер. Когда я в обработчике смотрю запрос то вижу что действительно пришел со страницы на которой делал редирект.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин В файле `Kernel.php`  с свойства `$middlewareGroups` с группы `web` я удалил импорт `            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` и все заработало но теперь сесия живет не только один запрос((

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94027/discussion-between---and-arendach).